# Ionic push notification clicked function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic push doc, I can't find method where it catch users' click. I tried below code but it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
"debug": true
});

      push.register(function(obj) {

        //save to db           


      });

      push.notificationCallback(function(data){
        console.log(data); // doesn't work
      })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send/receive push notifications from ionic mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004158/how-to-send-receive-push-notifications-from-ionic-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

This is the event for capturing notification click :

```
    push.on('notification', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
    });
```